# Side $BC$ of $\triangle ABC$..

Tags: geometry

Side $BC$ of $\triangle ABC$ and straight line $PQR$ are equal and parallel then prove that $\triangle AQR=\triangle PBQ$[image]

My Attempt 
If we join $RC$ we get $PRCB$ is a parallelogram.

Then what's next?

Comment: @N.S. JOHN, no the question hasn't specified anything like that.

Comment: I thought you meant that the triangles are congruent. I see you meant to prove the areas are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the altitude form $A$ to $BC$, intersecting $PR$ at $D$ and $BC$ at $E$. Draw the altitude from $Q$ to $BC$ and call the intersection $F$. This gives the areas
$$
|\triangle ABC| = |BC| \cdot |AE|\\ 
|\triangle APR| = |PR| \cdot |AD| = |BC| \cdot |AD|\\
|\triangle BCQ| = |BC| \cdot |QF|
$$
and also $|AD| + |QF| = |AE|$. Now we can calculate
$$
|\triangle BQP| = |\triangle ABC| + |\triangle AQR| - |\triangle APR| - |\triangle BCQ|\\
= |BC| \cdot |AE| + |\triangle AQR| - |BC| \cdot |AD| - |BC| \cdot |QF|\\
= |\triangle AQR| + |BC|\cdot\Big(|AE| - |AD| - |QF|\Big)\\
= |\triangle AQR| + |BC|\cdot 0 = |\triangle AQR|
$$

Comment: $|\triangle BQP| =|\triangle AQR|$. But $\triangle BQP \not =\triangle AQR$

Comment: @Roman83 Unless you're told more specific things about $\triangle ABC$, then that is not true. For instance, if $\angle ABC = 90^\circ$, then $\angle  BPQ = 90^\circ$, but $\triangle AQR$ has no right angles. So this is the best you can get.

Answer (score 1):

$\triangle ABC \sim \triangle APQ$ with dimension ratio $\frac{AP}{AB} = k$ (say).

Then if $\triangle ABC = A, \triangle APQ = k^2A$.

$\triangle APQ$ and $\triangle ABQ$ share the same altitude to $AB$ and have bases in the ratio of $k:1$. $\triangle ABQ = \frac{1}{k} \triangle APQ = kA$, so $\triangle PQB = (k - k^2)A$

$\triangle APR$ and $\triangle APQ$ share the same altitude to $PR$ and have bases in the ratio $1:k$. Hence $\triangle APR = \frac 1k \triangle APQ = kA$, giving $\triangle AQR = (k-k^2)A$.

Therefore $\triangle AQR = \triangle PBQ$

Answer (score 0):

In general, the statement is false

[image]

Comment: The question asks to show equality of area not congruence of triangles.